# PySpark AttributeError: type object 'ALS' has no attribute 'trainImplicit'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to train my dataset using ALS to find latent factors. My dataset is of **implicit** ratings.

In depth, my database consist of three columns User, Item (Repositories) and Rating (Number of Stars (Implicit Rating)):

```
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS

lines = spark.read.text("Dataset.csv").rdd
parts = lines.map(lambda row: row.value.split(","))

ratingsRDD = parts.map(lambda p: Row(userId=int(p[1]),repoId=int(p[2]),repoCount=float(p[3])))
ratings = spark.createDataFrame(ratingsRDD)

model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank=5,lambda_=0.01, alpha = 1.0, iterations =5)
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ALS' has no attribute 'trainImplicit'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the syntax from the old, [Spark MLLib ALS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.recommendation) (which works with RDDs, and not with dataframes) with the new, Spark ML ALS, which indeed doesn't have a `trainImplicit` attribute ([docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.recommendation)).

You should try something like:

```
als = ALS(rank=5, maxIter=5, alpha = 1.0, implicitPrefs=True, seed=0)
model = als.fit(ratings)
```

provided that your items are in a column named `item` and your ratings in `rating` - check the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.recommendation) for further details, parameterization options, and examples.